Issue with Aggregation from Two Collections in MongoDB
I'm trying to aggregate data from two collections in MongoDB but I'm running into an issue where the tagString and tagObject arrays are coming back empty. Here’s the context:
First, I retrieve a document from the dbChallenges collection:
db.dbchallenges.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("66ea89ef454ef534047b1ba8") }, { tags: 1 });

Result:
{
  _id: ObjectId('66ea89ef454ef534047b1ba8'),
  tags: [
    {
      tagID: ObjectId('66e8a25ee39bd5ecdc6628a8'),
      position: 0,
      _id: ObjectId('66ea89ef454ef534047b1ba9')
    }
  ]
}

Then, I check a document from the dbTags collection:
db.dbtags.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("66e8a25ee39bd5ecdc6628a8") });

Result:
{
  _id: ObjectId('66e8a25ee39bd5ecdc6628a8'),
  ro: 'Tutorial',
  en: 'Tutorial',
  master: true,
  __v: 0
}

Next, I attempt to aggregate the data:
db.dbchallenges.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: ObjectId("66ea89ef454ef534047b1ba8"),
    },
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      tagIDsAsObject: {
        $map: {
          input: "$tags",
          as: "tag",
          in: { $toObjectId: "$$tag.tagID" },
        },
      },
      tagIDsAsString: {
        $map: {
          input: "$tags",
          as: "tag",
          in: { $toString: "$$tag.tagID" },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "dbTags",
      let: { tagIdsStr: "$tagIDsAsString" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $addFields: { _idAsString: { $toString: "$_id" } },
        },
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: ["$_idAsString", "$$tagIdsStr"],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            _idAsString: 1,
            ro: 1,
            en: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "tagString",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "dbTags",
      localField: "tagIDsAsObject",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "tagObject",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      tags: 1,
      tagIDsAsObject: 1,
      tagIDsAsString: 1,
      tagString: 1,
      tagObject: 1,
    },
  },
]);

The result of the aggregation is as follows:
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('66ea89ef454ef534047b1ba8'),
    tags: [
      {
        tagID: ObjectId('66e8a25ee39bd5ecdc6628a8'),
        position: 0,
        _id: ObjectId('66ea89ef454ef534047b1ba9')
      }
    ],
    tagIDsAsObject: [ ObjectId('66e8a25ee39bd5ecdc6628a8') ],
    tagIDsAsString: [ '66e8a25ee39bd5ecdc6628a8' ],
    tagString: [],
    tagObject: []
  }
]

As you can see, both tagString and tagObject are empty, and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The problem seems like a typo error in your collection name in the $lookup. dbtags not dbTags. Demo

Thank you! I spent two days rewriting this code a million different ways.
